# WPF Project Folder File Bloat

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I work on my WPF project daily in Visual Studio 2022, and back-up my project folder in the evening. I can't help but notice the number of files in there just keeps getting greater (by hundreds every day), even when I'm not adding anything new to the project. It's causing back-up time, and the time it takes to transfer my files between workstations, to get longer and longer.

What could be generating these extra files and is there a way to minimize it?

I've had a look around the net for answers, but to no avail.

Thanks for all and any advice you can give me.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. What files in particular are being created, and in what folder?

Comment: I compared the current version project folder with a back-up of about a month ago.
It seems to all be in the obj\Debug\net6.0-windows folder. 
The difference over the month is about 3000 files. I think it's creating a new set of files everytime I run it, and never cleaning up the old ones.

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using a source repository?

Comment: @Jaydek I work on Visual Studio and would like to understand why this is happening, as it really should be occurring. Are you able to share some more details? In particular, what are some file names involved here. Ideally, file a feedback ticket (Help | Send feedback | Report a problem). If you can share your project privately with Microsoft engineers, that would be greatly helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Try compiling in release mode instead of debug mode.
2. Try clearing the obj and bin folders
3. Turn off the automatic generation of xml.

Update:
My guess is that you are running your program in debug mode and your program is causing some files to grow.
There are the following methods to clean up the obj folder:

1. Right-click the project and select clean, then rebuild
2. Add the following code into the pre-build event, so that the obj folder will be cleaned up before each build, but this operation will delete the previous obj folder.

```
rmdir /s /q "$(ProjectDir)obj"
```

Comment: I found the problem is with the obj folder. Is it ok to clear that folder without hurting my project?
In answer to your questions, yes, this happens with all my projects. Is there a setting I can change somewhere to automatically clean them out?

Comment: @Jaydek I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thank you. I believe this has sorted it. ^_^

Comment: @Jaydek If it helps you, you could upvote it too.

Comment: Done. My stack overflow account was too new to upvote before. But it appears I am now old enough. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve your problem is using the GitHub Repository.
Go to the Git Studio menu, select the create repository item in it, upload your Solution to the created Repository, commit the changes when you need it.
In addition to just backing up, this will allow you to easily and conveniently compare different versions.

If for some reason this is inconvenient for you, then pay attention to the ignore file in the Repository. All templated files and folders in this file do not require backup.

Here is a link to the ignore file from my Repository: https://github.com/EldHasp/CyberForumMyCycleRepos/blob/master/.gitignore

In the most minimal variant, all folders whose names begin with a dot, the bin, obj and packages folders do not require saving.

Comment: Git is just one example of numerous source repository options which include gitlab, azure and bit bucket.  I can't imagine why someone would not want to use a repository so this seems to almost certainly be the best option.

Comment: @Andy , I agree with you. The option with the "Git" menu was suggested as it is the easiest for those who do not yet know how to use the Repositories. When created through the "Git" menu in Studio, an ignore file well configured for Studio Solutions will be automatically added to the repository. If create the Repository in other ways, will most likely have to create this ignore file yourself. Which will be difficult for a beginner.

Comment: Fair point.  The same .gitignore wile would would work for any git based repo.  https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out. I used to code 20 years ago and am still transitioning to the new. I guess I've been putting off Git for too long.